# Nested ObservableCollection data binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am very new to WPF and trying to create a self learning application using WPF.
I am struggling to understand concepts like data binding,data templates,ItemControls to a full extent.

I am trying to create a learn page with the following requirements in mind.

1) The page can have more than one question.A scroll bar should be displayed once the
questions fills up the whole page. 
2) The format of the choices vary based on the question type.
3) the user shall be able to select the answer for the question.

I am facing problem with binding nested ObservableCollection and displaying the content as for the above requirements.

Can someone help in how to create a page as shown below and how to use INotifyPropertyChanged along XMAL to do the nested binding.

[image: myPage]

Here is the basic code I am trying to use to use display the questions and answers.

```
        namespace Learn
        {
            public enum QuestionType
            {
                OppositeMeanings,
                LinkWords
                //todo
            }
            public class Question
            {
                public Question()
                {
                    Choices = new ObservableCollection<Choice>();

                }
                public string Name { set; get; }
                public string Instruction { set; get; }
                public string Clue { set; get; }
                public ObservableCollection<Choice> Choices { set; get; }
                public QuestionType Qtype { set; get; }
                public Answer Ans { set; get; }
                public int Marks { set; get; }
            }
        }

        namespace Learn
        {
            public class Choice
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public bool isChecked { get; set; }
            }
        }
        namespace Learn
        {
            public class NestedItemsViewModel
            {
                public NestedItemsViewModel()
                {
                    Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        Question qn = new Question();

                        qn.Name = "Qn" + i;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                            Choice ch = new Choice();
                            ch.Name = "Choice" + j;
                            qn.Choices.Add(ch);
                        }
                        Questions.Add(qn);
                    }

                }

                public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
            }

            public partial class LearnPage : UserControl
            {

                public LearnPage()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    this.DataContext = new NestedItemsViewModel();

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You initial attempt gets you 80% of the way there. Hopefully, my answer will get you a little closer.

To start with, INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface an object supports to notify the Xaml engine that data has been modified and the user interface needs to be updated to show the change. You only need to do this on standard clr properties.

So if your data traffic is all one way, from the ui to the model, then there is no need for you to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I have created an example that uses the code you supplied, I have modified it and created a view to display it. The ViewModel and the data classes are as follows
    public enum QuestionType
    {
        OppositeMeanings,
        LinkWords
    }

```
public class Instruction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Choice selectedChoice;
    private string instruction;

    public Question()
    {
        Choices = new ObservableCollection<Choice>();

    }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public bool IsInstruction { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Instruction); } }
    public string Instruction
    {
        get { return instruction; }
        set
        {
            if (value != instruction)
            {
                instruction = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("IsInstruction");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Clue { set; get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Choice> Choices { set; get; }
    public QuestionType Qtype { set; get; }

    public Choice SelectedChoice
    {
        get { return selectedChoice; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedChoice)
            {
                selectedChoice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Marks { set; get; }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Choice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}

public class NestedItemsViewModel
{
    public NestedItemsViewModel()
    {
        Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
        for (var h = 0; h <= 1; h++)
        {
            Questions.Add(new Question() { Instruction = string.Format("Instruction {0}", h) });
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Question qn = new Question() { Name = "Qn" + ((4 * h) + i) };
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    qn.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Name = "Choice" + j, IsCorrect = j == i - 1 });
                }
                Questions.Add(qn);
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    internal void SelectChoice(int questionIndex, int choiceIndex)
    {
        var question = this.Questions[questionIndex];
        question.SelectedChoice = question.Choices[choiceIndex];
    }
}
```

Notice that Answer has been changed to a SelectedChoice. This may not be what you require but it made the example a little easier. i have also implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern on the SelectedChoice so I can set the SelectedChoice from code (*notably from a call to SelectChoice*).

The main windows code behind instantiates the ViewModel and handles a button event to set a choice from code behind (*purely to show INotifyPropertyChanged working*).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new NestedItemsViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public NestedItemsViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SelectChoice(3, 3);
    }
}
```

The Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20984156.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:learn="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._20984156"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <learn:SelectedItemIsCorrectToBooleanConverter x:Key="SelectedCheckedToBoolean" />

        <Style x:Key="ChoiceRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RadioButton}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedCheckedToBoolean}">
                            <Binding Path="IsCorrect" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedCheckedToBoolean}">
                            <Binding Path="IsCorrect" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="InstructionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type learn:Question}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Instruction}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type learn:Question}">
            <StackPanel Margin="10 0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Choices}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedChoice}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type learn:Choice}">
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Margin="10 1" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource ChoiceRadioButtonStyle}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Select Question 3 choice 3" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Questions}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <learn:QuestionTemplateSelector QuestionTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionTemplate}" InstructionTemplate="{StaticResource InstructionTemplate}" />
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

*Note: My learn namespace is different from yours so if you use this code, you will need to modify it to your namespace.*

So, the primary ListBox display a list of Questions. Each item in the ListBox (each Question) is rendered using a DataTemplate. Similarly, in the DataTemplate, a ListBox is used to display the choices and a DataTemplate is used to render each choice as a radio button.

Points of interest.

- Each choice is bound to the IsSelected property of the ListBoxItem it belongs to. It may not appear in the xaml but there will be a ListBoxItem for each choice. The IsSelected property is kept in sync with the SelectedItem property of the ListBox (by the ListBox) and that is bound to the SelectedChoice in your question.
- The choice ListBox has an ItemsPanel. This allows you to use the layout strategy of a different type of panel to layout the items of the ListBox. In this case, a horizontal StackPanel.
- I have added a button to set the choice of question 3 to 3 in the viewmodel. This will show you INotifyPropertyChanged working. If you remove the OnPropertyChanged call from the setter of the SelectedChoice property, the view will not reflect the change.

The example above does not handle the Instruction Type.

To handle instructions, I would either

1. Insert the instruction as a question and change the question DataTemplate so it does not display the choices for an instruction; or
2. Create a collection of Instructions in the view model where the Instruction type has a collection of questions (the view model would no longer have a collection of questions).

The Instruction class would be something like

```
public class Instruction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**Addition based on comment regarding timer expiration and multiple pages.**

The comments here are aimed at giving you enough information to know what to search for.

**INotifyPropertyChanged**

*If in doubt, implement INotifyPropertyChanged*. My comment above was to let you know why you use it. If you have data already displayed that will be manipulated from code, then you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

The ObservableCollection object is awesome for handling the manipulation of lists from code. Not only does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but it also implements INotifyCollectionChanged, both of these interfaces ensure that if the collection changes, the xaml engine knows about it and displays the changes. Note that if you modify a property of an object in the collection, it will be up to you to notify the Xaml engine of the change by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the object. The ObservableCollection is awesome, not omnipercipient.

**Paging**

For your scenario, paging is simple. Store the complete list of questions somewhere (memory, database, file). When you go to page 1, query the store for those questions and populate the ObservableCollection with those questions. When you go to page 2, query the store for page 2 questions, CLEAR the ObservableCollection and re populate. If you instantiate the ObservableCollection once and then clear and repopulate it while paging, the ListBox refresh will be handled for you.

**Timers**

Timers are pretty resource intensive from a windows point of view and as such, should be used sparingly. There are a number of timers in .net you can use. I tend to play with [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both of these invoke the timer callback on a thread other than the DispatcherThread, which allows you to do work without affecting the UI responsiveness. However, if during the work you need to modify the UI, you will need to [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get back on the Dispatcher thread. BeginInvoke is asynchronous and therefore, should not hang the thread while it waits for the DispatcherThread to become idle.

**Addition based on comment regarding separation of data templates.**

I added an IsInstruction to the Question object (I did not implement a Instruction class). This shows an example of raising the PropertyChanged event from property A (Instruction) for Property B (IsInstruction).

I moved the DataTemplate from the list box to the Window.Resources and gave it a key. I also created a second DataTemplate for the instruction items.

I created a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to choose which DataTemplate to use. DataTemplateSelectors are good when you need to select a DataTemplate as the Data is being loaded. Consider it a OneTime selector. If you required the DataTemplate to change during the scope of the data it is rendering, then you should use a trigger. The code for the selector is

```
public class QuestionTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate template = null;

        var question = item as Question;
        if (question != null)
        {
            template = question.IsInstruction ? InstructionTemplate : QuestionTemplate;
            if (template == null)
            {
                template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        return template;
    }

    public DataTemplate QuestionTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate InstructionTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

The selector is bound to the ItemTemplateSelector of the ItemsControl.

Finally, I converted the ListBox into an ItemsControl. The ItemsControl has most of the functionality of a ListBox (the ListBox control is derived from an ItemsControl) but it lacks the Selected functionality. It will make your questions seem more like a page of questions than a list.

*NOTE: Although I only added the code of the DataTemplateSelector to the addition, I updated the code snipits throughout the rest of the answer to work with the new DataTemplateSelector.*

**Addition based on comment regarding setting the background for right and wrong answers**

Setting the background dynamically based on values in the model requires a trigger, in this case, multiple triggers.

I have updated the Choice object to include an IsCorrect and during the creation of the questions in the ViewModel, I have assigned IsCorrect on one of the Choices for each answer.

I have also updated the MainWindow to include style triggers on the RadioButton. There are a few points to not about triggers
1. The style or the RadioButton sets the backgound when the mouse is over. A fix would require recreating the style of the RadioButton.
1. Since the trigger is based on 2 values, we can either create another property on the model to combine the 2 properties, or use MultiBinding and a MultValueConverter. I have used the [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [MultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is as follows.

```
public class SelectedItemIsCorrectToBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValues = values.OfType<bool>().ToList();

        var isCorrectValue = boolValues[0];
        var isSelected = boolValues[1];

        if (isSelected)
        {
            return isCorrectValue;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Mark.This certainly helps.I wanted to disable the choices once the timer expires and if the user selects next i want to refresh the page and display new questions and choices.In this case don't you think INotifyPropertyChanged is needed? Pls let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you Mark...Now I can easily implement my app :)

Comment: Mark..It has worked..Thank You..but how do I do a separate data template for each instruction as shown in the above pic(i.e questions and choices under particular instruction type should have one data template ,questions and choices under another instruction type should have different data template)

Comment: There a two ways. First you will need to create to DataTemplate resources and give them names (keys), one for instruction and one for question. In the first solution you create a ItemsContainerStyle and based on data, use triggers to set the ContentTemplate. The second solution is to create a DataTemplateSelector. I have updated the answer to show the separation of DataTemplates for questions and instructions using a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: I hope you dont mind.Is there any way we can select a different template for each question and choice based on QuestionType.As shown in the diagram,In Section1 and Section2,the background colour of questions is different and the way choices are displayed is different.In section2 the choices 1,2 and 3,4 are separated by a GridSplitter and their background colour is different.I am thinking to have class for each instruction with Instruction as base class (based on QuestionType)and load the corresponding templates for instruction,question and choices by calling virtual method.Any thoughts on this

Comment: Mark...sorry to trouble you again...If I select Validate button in the above window..How do I set the background colour of the selected choice to red colour if the user select wrong answer and the background colour to green if the user selects right answer.....I mean by using data binding.

Comment: Hey Ven, you can change the background colour through the use of Triggers. Create a style of the control you want to set the background for. In the style create a DataTrigger and set the Binding property (a standard binding expression) and the value. When the trigger is true, the setters inside the trigger are applied. When the trigger is false, the setters are removed and the default setters are applied. Note the background of a RadioButton is inside the circle. I have upaded the answer with the necessary code and description.

Comment: Thank you again Mark...much much helpful.I am assuming Triggers are the way forward for applying different template for each question and choice based on QuestionType(my comment prior to last one).

Comment: I would use triggers if the template or style can change during the lifetime of the control. I would use a DataTemplateSelector if; a - a template is chosen when the control is created and that template is used for the lifetime of the control; **and** b - if the control supports a DataTemplate Selector.

Comment: Hi Mark...Is it possible for you to help me with the question [Loading Different DataTemplate for each item in ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111817/loading-different-datatemplate-for-each-item-in-listbox)